# Make a free function behave like a member function (C++)

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, std, c++17

Assuming I have a function like the following in C++:

```
template<typename Container>
void doNothing(Container * container) {
    for (auto element: container) {
         std::cout << element;
    }
}
```

Would it be possible to "simulate"  methods on various classes that could implement this function by passing `this` to it instead of the first parameter. (E.g. a class like std::vector, std::string ... etc).

So basically instead of having to use it as:

```
std::vector<double> a{1, 2, 0.5}:
doNothing(a);
```

I could call it as:

```
std::vector<double> a{1, 2, 0.5}:
a.doNothing();
```

Comment: what is wrong with `doNothing(a)`? Is the question only about being able to write it differently or anything beyond that?

Comment: IMHO your going the wrong way.  If you have a task to complete and it can be generalized for a number of different classes then why make it a member and have all the scaffolding to do that when a single free function accomplishes the same thing and is a lot easier to pull into other projects.

Comment: I don't see the problem actually? Am I dumb? You can't extend `std::vector` but you always are able to wrap it for your needs.

Comment: you can always overload pointer-to-member operator and call it like `(a->*doNothing)()`, but as suggested reconsider... C++ is not a C#

Comment: @tobi303 The question is about being able to write it differently in the sense that, for a large project, other users could gain knowledge from whatever autcomplete they use about the method existing on the specific class. However reconsidering the question if such a thing would be possible via metaprogramming any autocomplete would probably not be able to detect it (since I don't know of one that looks at the code generated after compilation and I'm not sure its even feasably possible to write one)

Comment: the knowlegde of an interface should not be based on some autocomplete feature. Note that usually free functions are considered part of the interface of a class. Take for example the input/output operator for streams, that arent member functions, but definitely part of a class interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do that.

The `this` parameter in the call `a.b()` is implicit, and there's no way to fake an implicit parameter.

The `a.b()` syntax is simply not available to you unless `b` is a member.

Comment: Just curious: Isn't overloading the dot operator coming?  If we had that then how would it work?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah: From Google: https://isocpp.org/blog/2016/02/a-bit-of-background-for-the-operator-dot-proposal-bjarne-stroustrup

Comment: Thanks!  That's very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can always simulate a member function by passing the `this` pointer of an object.
After all, that's all the compiler is doing for proper member functions (passing `this` as a hidden first parameter).

So, if you want a function `foo` to behave like a member and operate on an object (ignoring private/protected here) of type `Bar`, then you could declare it as:

```
void foo(Bar* self);
```

and call it like

```
Bar b;
foo(&b);
```

(or from inside a `Bar` member: `foo(this);`)

then it would be able to access members of `b` and call its functions by dereferencing the `self` pointer.

Answer (score 1):

```
template<class F>
struct poly_mem_ptr_t{
  F f;
  template<class T>
  friend auto operator->*( T* t, poly_mem_ptr_t self )const{
    return
      [t, f=self.f](auto&&...args)->decltype(auto){
        return f(t, decltype(args)(args)...); 
      };
  }
  template<class T>
  friend auto operator->*( T& t, poly_mem_ptr_t self )const{
    return std::addressof(t)->*self;
  }
};

template<class F>
poly_mem_ptr_t<F> poly_mem_ptr(F f){ return {std::move(f)}; }
```

Sample use:

```
auto do_nothing = poly_mem_ptr([](auto* ptr){ doNothing(ptr); });

std::vector<int> v={1,2,3};
(v->*do_nothing)();
```

not exactly what you want, but close.

As a benefit, you can add

```
  template<class...Ts>
  friend decltype(auto) operator->*( std::variant<Ts...>& var, poly_mem_ptr_t self )const{
    return [&var, f=self.f](auto&&...args) {
      return std::visit( [&](auto&&t)->decltype(auto){
        return f( decltype(t)(t), decltype(args)(args)... );
      }, var);
    };
  }
```

and now you can take a `std::variant` and use these `poly_mem_ptr`s as visitors.

With a bit of work you can also tool up an augmented `std::any` to support a fixed set of `poly_mem_ptr`s.